# Unexpected results in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, operators, concatenation

Using the node.js console, I get the following unexpected results:

```
> 2 + "3"
"23"

> 2 * "3"
6
```

Why does the first example favor string concatenation and integer multiplication in the second example?  I would not expect concatenation between different types, but rather an error to be thrown.  If this is the behavior in JS, how can I predict the type of the final result?

Comment: Because the + operator can be used for numeric addition and concatenation. One operand is a string thus stringification and concatenation happens. The * operator can only be used for numeric multiplication and both operands are converted to integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification ([Addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus), [Multiplicative operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators)), the evaluation of additive expression is (`lprim` is the left primitive (lval converted to primitive), `rprim` is the right one):

```
 ...
 If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
     Let lstr be ToString(lprim).
     ReturnIfAbrupt(lstr).
     Let rstr be ToString(rprim).
     ReturnIfAbrupt(rstr).
     Return the String that is the result of concatenating lstr and rstr.
 Let lnum be ToNumber(lprim).
 ReturnIfAbrupt(lnum).
 Let rnum be ToNumber(rprim).
 ReturnIfAbrupt(rnum).
 Return the result of applying the addition operation to lnum and rnum.
```

The evaluation of multiplicative expression is:

```
...
Let lnum be ToNumber(leftValue).
ReturnIfAbrupt(lnum).
Let rnum be ToNumber(rightValue).
ReturnIfAbrupt(rnum).
Return the result of applying the MultiplicativeOperator
```

You can see that if it is an additive expression, it is first to check whether there is a String. If there is a String, string concatenation is executed. Otherwise, the values are converted to Number and an addition operation is executed.

If it is a multiplicative expression, it would always convert values to Number and deliver a multiplicative operation.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript the `+` operator serves as both addition and concatenation (joining two strings together) and will default to concatenation when one of the two values is a string.

Since you are using it between an integer and a string it will default to concatentation.  If you ever need to force the addition operation you will need to make sure all of your values are numbers.  You can do this with `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` functions.

`2 + parseInt("3"); // 5`

The `*` operator is for multiplication only and as such it will automatically cast strings to numbers to perform the operation.

Given the above there's another trick you can use to force string numbers to actually become numbers which is multiplying them by 1 `*1`.

`2 + "3"*1; // 5`